# Hibernation annotations, specify column default value

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a domain object and annotated as follows

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "REQUEST")
 public class Request {

  /**
   * Unique id for this request
   */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "EQ_ID")
private long requestId;
/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
private String emailId;
/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE")
private Date requestDate;
/**
*Getters/setters omitted
*/
 }
```

The column **Request_date** cannot be null and as per the DDL the default value is sysdate (oracle DB). How do I annotate this field so that if the requestDate property is null,hiberanate automatically inserts sysdate.? Currently it throws error when the field is null,which is very obvious as it cannot be null as per the DB constraints. How do I go about this?
One alternative is to mark this field as transient and the inserts work fine. But the negative aspect is that, I will not be able to retrieve the value (of request_date column).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a missing feature in hibernate annotations. Also there exist some workaround as Yok has posted. The problem is that the workaround is vendor dependent and might not work for all DB. In my case,Oracle, it isn't working and has been reported as a bug.

Answer (score 8):

You can put the default value in a columnDefinition. An example would look like:

```
@Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "date default sysdate")
```

Comment: I have tried it already. @Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE", columnDefinition = "DATE  DEFAULT sysdate   NOT NULL"). It doesn't work.

Comment: @chedine: Please mention in your question what you already tried and why it doesn't work for you. See my other comment for rationale behind this.

Comment: @chedine: What error does it throw ? when you use solution similar to mine. Coz I am using this and don't face any issue.

Comment: As per this, http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4341, the solution is vendor specific and unfortunately doesn't work with oracle. Not having the ability to specify the default value seems to be a missing feature.

Comment: Please refer my comment to @WW post

Comment: Can you drop existing table and retry and check Table definition created in your database. Does it have "default sysdate" for date column.

Comment: Yes it has "default sysdate". The solution is not gonna work with Oracle.It works fine with MYSQL.

Comment: Just try removing "NOT NULL". And check does it function as intended, i.e. put sysdate if nothing is passed.

Another thing I would like to see is, what query is being fired ? You can run hibernate in debug mode with show query option.

Answer (score 4):

Using @ColumnDefault  (Work for DDL update).
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;

....

@ColumnDefault(value="'@'")
@Column(name = "TEMP_COLUMN", nullable = false)
public String getTempColumn() {
    return tempColumn;
}
```

DDL Generate:

```
Alter Table YOUR_TABLE add TEMP_COLUMN varchar2(255) default '@' not null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign a default value to the field:

```
private Date requestDate = new Date();
```

Comment: This is a web application. The above line will insert server time which will be different from sysdate (assuming the appserver and db are in diff timezones). Also the same code will be running in different development servers but all pointing to same db instance.

Comment: @chedine: If you have specific constraints, why don't you add them in the question?! You would better answers and people wouldn't waste their time suggesting something that doesn't match your constraints...

Comment: I'll still leave this answer for the benefit of people with different constraints than yours.

Comment: Helped me, nice that you left it here

Answer (score 1):

If you mark your entity with `@DynamicInsert` e.g.

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class ClassName implements Serializable  {
```

Hibernate will generate SQL without `null` values.    Then the database will insert its own default value. This does have performance implications See [Dynamic Insert](https://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-dynamic-insert-attriburte-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Make the default in Oracle for the column SYSDATE:

`ALTER TABLE APP MODIFY (REQUEST_DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE);`

Then, from Hibernate's perspective it can be nullable.

Hibernate will save a NULL to the database. Oracle will convert that to SYSDATE. And everyone will be happy.

Comment: That is how it is now. But I get an exception when i try to insert a object with requestdate=null. Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DBINST"."APP"."REQUEST_DATE")

Comment: If you run the same INSERT from SQL*Plus or something, does it work or give you that error?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved assigning a value to the variable like this *private Integer active= 0;*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")

public class ServiziTipologia {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Integer id;
     private String product;
     private String description;
     private Integer active= 0;
```